# prevent kendo ui chart tooltip from disappearing after chart refresh

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart, kendo-tooltip

I have a Kendo UI Chart that contains data that updates every couple of seconds. When the user hovers over the data point a Kendo Chart tooltip appears. However, when new data comes in and the chart is refreshed, Kendo hides the current tooltip, giving the user very little time to read the tooltip.

After looking at the Kendo Chart [doc](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#methods), I tried to use `showTooltip()` after the chart was refreshed, but was confused with what the `filter` parameter would be. We have multiple data points on the chart and every point has its own tooltip.

Here is what I have so far:

```
seriesHover: function (e) {
    prevTooltip = e.value;
}

chart.showTooltip(function (point) {
    return point.value === prevTooltip;
});
```

However, it doesn't seem to filter and find the right data point so the tooltip does not get shown.

> I would like to refresh the tooltip along with the chart. If a tooltip was active before the chart refresh, then it should update and remain visible after the refresh